# Adding key, value into dictionary

Tags: python, dictionary

I am trying to add dictionaries which have a key from each element from the list and value(s) from one following element from the list. For example, if the key is "the", the values are "cat" and "dog".

I was not sure why I got an error on the line `output[item] = f[i+1]`.
Could someone help?
My code is:

```
line = ['The', 'cat', 'chased', 'the', 'dog']
output = {}
for i, item in enumerate(line):
   output[item] = line[i+1]
print output
```

The error is: `IndexError: list index out of range` on the line `output[item] = f[i+1]`

Comment: what is `f` variable?

Comment: Sorry, that was a typo.. Thank you for pointing out :)

Comment: The error is thrown for the last element of the list as there is no next element available. You need to stop the iteration at the second last element or do something else based on your requirements. For example, go the first element when `i == len(line) - 1 `.

Comment: or just enumerate `line[:-1]`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

What ozgur said, except that you can get rid of the `if` statement and enumeration if you zip your list with a version of your list starting at element 1:

```
import collections

line = ['The', 'cat', 'chased', 'the', 'dog']
output = collections.defaultdict(list)
for (x, y) in zip(line, line[1:]):
    output[x.lower()].append(y)
print(output)
```

Answer (score 2):

You need to stop the iteration before processing the last element in the list because there is no `next` item after the last one.

```
>>> import collections

>>> line = ['The', 'cat', 'chased', 'the', 'dog']
>>> output = collections.defaultdict(list)

>>> for i, item in enumerate(line):
...     if i < len(line) - 1:
...         output[item.lower()].append(line[i+1])

>>> print output
{'the': ['cat', 'dog'], 'chased': ['the'], 'cat': ['chased']}
```

Alternatively, in case you might want to eliminate `if`;

```
>>> for i in range(len(line) - 1):
...     output[line[i].lower()].append(line[i+1])
```

Comment: Thank you for the answer. I ran the code but I got the error below. 
"TypeError: first argument must be callable" for "output = collections.defaultdict(list)". Could you please tell me why this is happening?

Comment: You have a variable named `list`. Please rename your variable to something else, for instance `lst`. It's not a good habit to use names of built-ins because they will override the name of the built-in in that scope.

Answer (score 1):

line[0:4] is valid, but line[5] is not.

Try this:

```
line = ['The', 'cat', 'chased', 'the', 'dog']
output = {}
for i, item in enumerate(line):
    print(i, item, len(line))
    if i != len(line) - 1:
        output[item] = line[i+1]
    else:
        output[item] = None
print(output)
```